# run pentaho kettle from cmd. how to send the source files as a param?

Tags: java, etl, pentaho, kettle

I'm using Pentaho Kettle 4.0.1. Now I run a transformation from Java by providing a transformation file (XML type not KTR) and give some other XML files (in a src folder) that are meant to be inserted or updated in DB.

What I want is to do these things from a bat or shell file and not from Java. I'm not completely familiarized with kettle... I've seen some example regarding running a kettle transformation from a .bat file but there only is a file parameter that receives the transformation file (ktr). How do I pass as a param to pan.bat/pan.sh the src dir where my xml data files are (the data that is about to be inserted in DB)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to read this:
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Pan+User+Documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax for sh file

sh pan.sh -file:Transformation1.ktr -param:parameter1=myname -param:parameter2=30

Answer (score 0):

You can use transformations named parameters to capture the xml files path

[Here you can see an example](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Named+Parameters),

[This is other way](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?49116-can-we-pass-kettle-properties-as-parameter-to-spoon-pan-chef-kitchen)

Comment: I don't understand ... I don't see anywhere a dir/files param.

Comment: How you think you could use (or are you using) this paramater in your transformation or steps??